# Can I put MacBookPro5,1 RAM in a MacBookPro5,2?

Tags: macbook-pro, memory

I have an old 5,2 17” June 8, 2009 MacBook Pro that I want to upgrade the RAM in, can I put some slightly older MacBookPro5,1 RAM in it, or will it not function right? I’m assuming it will mess up the machine if I put older RAM in it but im not sure. It’s crucial ram and there are two 4GB sticks, if that helps at all, thanks again!

Liam

Answer (score 1):

Both MBPs use the same RAM architecture: 204-pin PC3-8500 (1066MHz) DDR3 SO-DIMM.

Information from macOS app [MacTracker](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mactracker/id430255202?mt=12).

8GB is the maximum supported RAM for this MBP.

Disclaimer: I'm a satisfied user of MacTracker and have no financial or other connection with the developer Ian Page.

Comment: So you’re saying that it should work if I take out the older stick and put in two of the other 4GB ones it will work?

Comment: Yes. Identical RAM. Follow instructions at [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201165) on how to replace. [Video from OWC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FGiOVKzNh7w&frags=pl%2Cwn) has some rocking' tunes! Be methodical and minimize static.

Comment: Mactracker so good & useful.